# Como eu calculo as funções "positives" e "negatives" de um arquivo json para HTML em porcentagem?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

Salve, possuo um arquivo JSON com variáveis "positives" e "negatives", gostaria de transformar esses valores em porcentagem, "positives" sendo "Gostam" e "negatives" sendo "Não gostam".
Após isso como eu poderia organizar os profiles com base nesses dados?

Arquivo JSON:

```
{
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "box_name": "A Fazenda - Ranking",
  "data": [
    {
      "__id": "f8c3500f39017602234a031caa64a8b4",
      "timestamp": 1408396531382,
      "name": "Rita Cadillac",
      "description": "Cracrete n&ordm;1",
      "picture": "http://im.r7.com/record/files/2C96/1617/3F6E/32AE/013F/72F9/AD72/3CE1/RitaCadillac1.jpg",
      "positive": 51638022,
      "negative": 18143089
    },
    {
      "__id": "7b1dd3f58be97715e9e06475bb58fce5",
      "timestamp": 1408396481826,
      "name": "Gominho",
      "description": "Fofoqueiro de Plantão",
      "picture": "http://im.r7.com/record/files/2C96/1618/3F6E/369D/013F/72F7/CF15/5F4B/Gominho1.jpg",
      "positive": "23249923",
      "negative": "39587707"
    },
    {
      "__id": "70580002438b08c63286d08b7c43fb4c",
      "timestamp": 1408396545027,
      "name": "Yudi Tamashiro",
      "description": "Apresentador e ídolo teen",
      "picture": "http://im.r7.com/record/files/2C96/1617/3F6E/32AE/013F/72FD/87BB/4436/Yudi1.jpg",
      "positive": 59089056,
      "negative": 14772265
    },
    {
      "__id": "3404c4a70e7704009cd1915a349189f4",
      "timestamp": 1408396555971,
      "name": "Andressa Urach",
      "description": "Personalidade da mídia",
      "picture": "http://im.r7.com/record/files/2C96/1618/3F6E/369D/013F/72EF/C598/41DC/Andressa1.jpg",
      "positive": null,
      "age": 32
    },
    {
      "__id": "c97686edbeb8df774a567e9884f4d490",
      "timestamp": 1408396562866,
      "name": "Bárbara Evans",
      "description": "Modelo e filha de Monique Evans",
      "picture": "http://im.r7.com/record/files/2C96/1618/3F6E/369D/013F/72F6/B48C/5BBD/B%C3%A1rbaraEvans1.jpg",
      "positive": 69274684,
      "negative": 9446548
    }
  ]
}
```

PS: Não posso alterar nada desses arquivos.

Comment: "Organizar" em que sentido?

Comment: Dar sort nos itens, dependendo do mais votado positivamento colocar o mesmo em primeiro na lista e o menos votado positivamento por ultimo na lista

Comment: 100% seria a soma dos positivos e negativos?

Comment: Mas o que são esses valores em `positive` e `negative` ? Eles certamente não parecem contagens.

Comment: Vc já tem a lista? É um HTML já pronto ou vc quer criar um depois dos resultados?

Comment: @dvd tenho uma lista sim, porém com outros valores

Comment: Com a solução que coloquei como resposta você consegue organizar. Além de inserir as porcentagens nos objetos, eu reorganizei a array em ordem de votos. Com isso vc pode montar a lista como quiser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar um `for...of` no JSON pela array `data` e ir calculando os valores (veja explicações no código) ao mesmo tempo que vai adicionando duas novas entradas nos objetos: `gostam` e `não gostam`, cada qual com a sua respectiva porcentagem em relação ao total de votos (soma de `positive` e `negative`).

Criei uma tabela ilustrativa para mostrar os resultados:

```js
var json = {
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "box_name": "A Fazenda - Ranking",
  "data": [
    {
      "__id": "f8c3500f39017602234a031caa64a8b4",
      "timestamp": 1408396531382,
      "name": "Rita Cadillac",
      "description": "Cracrete n&ordm;1",
      "picture": "http://im.r7.com/record/files/2C96/1617/3F6E/32AE/013F/72F9/AD72/3CE1/RitaCadillac1.jpg",
      "positive": 51638022,
      "negative": 18143089
    },
    {
      "__id": "7b1dd3f58be97715e9e06475bb58fce5",
      "timestamp": 1408396481826,
      "name": "Gominho",
      "description": "Fofoqueiro de Plantão",
      "picture": "http://im.r7.com/record/files/2C96/1618/3F6E/369D/013F/72F7/CF15/5F4B/Gominho1.jpg",
      "positive": "23249923",
      "negative": "39587707"
    },
    {
      "__id": "70580002438b08c63286d08b7c43fb4c",
      "timestamp": 1408396545027,
      "name": "Yudi Tamashiro",
      "description": "Apresentador e ídolo teen",
      "picture": "http://im.r7.com/record/files/2C96/1617/3F6E/32AE/013F/72FD/87BB/4436/Yudi1.jpg",
      "positive": 59089056,
      "negative": 14772265
    },
    {
      "__id": "3404c4a70e7704009cd1915a349189f4",
      "timestamp": 1408396555971,
      "name": "Andressa Urach",
      "description": "Personalidade da mídia",
      "picture": "http://im.r7.com/record/files/2C96/1618/3F6E/369D/013F/72EF/C598/41DC/Andressa1.jpg",
      "positive": null,
      "age": 32
    },
    {
      "__id": "c97686edbeb8df774a567e9884f4d490",
      "timestamp": 1408396562866,
      "name": "Bárbara Evans",
      "description": "Modelo e filha de Monique Evans",
      "picture": "http://im.r7.com/record/files/2C96/1618/3F6E/369D/013F/72F6/B48C/5BBD/B%C3%A1rbaraEvans1.jpg",
      "positive": 69274684,
      "negative": 9446548
    }
  ]
}

for(var item of json.data){
   // pega os valores. Se for vazio ou null considera zero
   var posit = item.positive || 0;
   var negat = item.negative || 0;
   var total = parseInt(posit) + parseInt(negat); // soma os dois valores
   // pega a porcentagem e dispensa as decimais
   var gostam = ((posit*100) / total).toFixed(0);
   var naogostam = ((negat*100) / total).toFixed(0);
   
   // insere novas entradas no objeto
   item['gostam'] = isNaN(gostam) ? 0 : gostam;
   item['não gostam'] = isNaN(naogostam) ? 0 : naogostam;
}

// organiza o JSON com os que tem mais votos "gostei" em ordem decrescete
json.data.sort(function(a,b){
   return a.gostam < b.gostam;
});

// aqui irá inserir na tabela os resultados
var res = document.getElementById("resultado");
var html = '<caption>'+json.box_name+'</caption>'
    +'<tr><td>NOME</td><td>% GOSTAM</td><td>% NÃO GOSTAM</td></tr>';
for(var item of json.data){
   html += '<tr><td>'+item.name+'</td><td>'+item.gostam+'</td><td>'+item['não gostam']+'</td></tr>';
}

res.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
td{
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="5" border="1" id="resultado"></table>
```

Comment: Cara adorei tudo, porém não teria como fazer uma solução que não editasse o json e fizesse com retrieve no html?

Comment: Pode fazer uma cópia do json: `var copia = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));`

Comment: Fazendo uma cópia, vc altera apenas a cópia e deixa o original intacto. Serve assim? Eu atualizo a resposta.

Comment: Serve sim, valeu

Comment: Pronto. Resposta atualizada! Abs!